# Is there something similar to WPF DataTemplates in GTK/Glade?

Tags: templates, gtk, glade

I am coding a pyGTK application, and I'd like to change an input based on the user's selection from a ComboBox. For example, a user could select truck/car/van, and the input parameters would change corresponding to the type of vehicle.

Is there a way one can define the different sub-panels using Glade? It would be easy to just define a new class for each different sub-panel, but is it possible to also do this in Glade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In glade (at least for glade-3 that uses GtkBuilder), you can have any widget as a top-level widget so you can design those panels and then insert them into appropriate container.